# Create a Page in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am learning Angular JS

Here is my **app.js**

```
.when('/forget', {
                title: 'forget',
                templateUrl: 'resources/views/forget.php',
                controller: 'genCtrl'

            })
.otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/login'
            });
```

I want to display the `forget.php` file inside `resources/views` folder

Here is my **genCtrl**

```
app.controller('genCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, $http, Data) {
    //initially set those objects to null to avoid undefined error
    $scope.forget = function () 
    {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

When ever i do `http://localhost/myapp/#/forget` the browser is displaying the content of `forget.php` and then suddenly taking me to `/login`.

How can i remain in the same page ?

Update :

Here is my [app.js](http://jsfiddle.net/7z3kuwwd/)

Here is my [genCtrl.js](http://jsfiddle.net/mfr2r6dn/)

Here is the console

[image]

Comment: Why so many parameters in controller? What is Data here? Do you see any error in console?

Comment: @nikhil How many parameters should i have.. And no i can't see the error in console, as it is redirecting me to the /login , but few times i am seeing this error in console docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=genCtrl&p1=not

Comment: You should have only the required parameters. As of now you need only $scope. So, I will suggest keep only $scope and remove all others and then check.

Comment: Are you using html5mode ?

Comment: Dude, try to read this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07, if you have not read it yet. Looks like you set up up you app wrongly.

Comment: @nikhil Thanks, i used only $scope.. Stil same error

Comment: @MertMertce I am using regularly in browser..

Comment: @Alex I just download it from a tutorial, which works good :(

Comment: @CableRaja Try this: (Assuming you are injecting locationProvider)
.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'}); $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
And then try to connect without #: http://localhost/myapp/forget

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` near the `genCtrl`

Comment: @MertMertce where can i do `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');`

Comment: @CableRaja Also you should set your base in your html: <base href="/myapp">

Comment: @CableRaja in .config(). You can put after .otherwise statement; and you need to inject $locationProvider.

Comment: @MertMertce If i add <base href="/myapp"> , then few of my css is not applying..

Comment: @CableRaja You are adding it within <head/> ? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: @MertMertce Yes i did the same

Comment: @CableRaja then it depends how you wrote your links to css. Instead of using absolute paths, use relative paths (without /). (I have assumed that your root path is 'myapp' btw)

Comment: Ah, i am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error now

Comment: @CableRaja if you provide us jsfiddle we can help you much better.

Comment: @MertMertce I have updated the jsfiddle in my question

Comment: I had meant a running example; but anyway the line that causes you to return login could be app.js@56 ($location.path("/login");).

Comment: @MertMertce I tried removing it, but it was still the same

Comment: your screenshot tells that app is undefined. Did you put your genCtrl in another js? There is way to separate your codes and add to the same module, but not that way. Try to start simply and put all your codes about angular in same js and get your code work. Then you can look how to organize your code.

Comment: @Mert Mertce Yes, I have it in different js.. I tried to put inside the app.js itself.. That also causes same error...

Comment: @CableRaja Delete extra comma at line 30:  controller: 'listCtrl',

Answer (score 0):

Inspite of writing return '1', please write alert('test') and check the prompt message 'test' and this will not throw you in login page.

AngularJS will invoke the controller with a `$scope` object. `$scope` is the application object (the owner of application variables and functions), to know more about these services please check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service) link OR [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

PS: If this stuff helps you please leave me a comment and support :)

Thanks!